# Insert array of objects using TypeORM in typrscript in table

Tags: typescript, postgresql, typeorm

suppose we have a table of fruits and we want to insert multiple record in one query using TypeORM

```js
apple = {
    color: "Green",
    name:  "apple",
    price: 400
}
banana = {
    color: "yellow",
    name:  "banana",
    price: 700
}
fruits = [apple, banana]
repo = repository(fruit_repo)
repo.insert(fruits)
```

The last line does not work for list how do i insert in one query without a for loop

Answer (score 1):

It really depends in the modeling of the entities.

Let's say you have an entity holding a relation to another Fruit entity in a `many` form,  you can use `cascade: true`, and then TypeORM will save the array in a single line, also creating the fruit entities.

Please view TypeORM docs for further information.